# Модификация живого поиска, добавить radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма живого поиска (liveserarch)

```
<div id="lscontainer">
    <div class="starter-template-purple">

        <div class="page-header">
            Живой телефонный справочник<sup style="color: tomato; vertical-align: top;">&beta;</sup>
        </div>

        <form role="form" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" placeholder="Введите слово..." autocomplete="off">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group"><center>
            <table style="width: 80%;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="33%"><input type="radio" name="search_type" value="by_address" id="radio4" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked" />
                        <label for="radio4" class="css-label radGroup2">по адресу </label>
                    </td>
                    <td width="34%"><input type="radio" name="search_type" value="by_name" id="radio5" class="css-checkbox" />
                        <label for="radio5" class="css-label radGroup2">по фамилии </label>
                    </td>
                    <td width="33%"><input type="radio" name="search_type" value="by_phone" id="radio6" class="css-checkbox" />
                        <label for="radio6" class="css-label radGroup2">по телефону </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </center></div>

        </form>


    </div>
</div>
```

и JavaScript в который отправляется POST методом значение input (id="keyword") для search.clients.inc.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#keyword').on('input', function() {
        var searchKeyword = $(this).val();

        if (searchKeyword.length >= 3) {
            $.post('search.clients.inc.php', { keywords: searchKeyword }, function(data) {
                $('div#content-ls').empty()
                $.each(data, function() {
                    $('div#content-ls').append('<div class="boxer-lte"> <span class="box2"><b>' + this.db_name + ',</b> ' + this.db_address + '</span> <span class="box3">' + this.db_phones + '' + this.db_district  + '<span> </div>');
                });
            }, "json");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Вопрос: как модифицировать JavaScript код что бы он отправлял в search.clients.inc.php еще и выбранное значения radio.

http://www.finalwebsites.com/jquery-ajax-live-search/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var searchKeyword = $(this).val();
var searchBy = $('input[name="search_type"]:checked').val();

if (searchKeyword.length >= 3) {    
  $.post('search.clients.inc.php', 
    { keywords: searchKeyword, searchType: searchBy }, 
    function(data) {
      ...
```